# How do I click a javascript:void(0) button in SeleniumWebdriver Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, jira

I am having difficulty clicking a Javascript:void(0) button with an "x" text in Selenium Java.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="aui-button aui-button-link aui-restfultable-delete aui-restfultable-delete-small" original-title="Delete resolved">x</a>
```

It is a small x button that opens up another window to confirm delete but I am unable to get to the confirm window in Selenium using Java.

At the moment I have used the below but all came up with errors.

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("x")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#request-types-table a.aui-restfultable-delete-small").click();
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried switching to alert ?? 

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.aui-button.aui-button-link.aui-restfultable-delete.aui-restfultable-delete-small").click();
```

Comment: Thank You! I can see that it is working because it is highlighting but the first x is disabled, how do I get Selenium to move to second x without moving to the next step altogether?

Comment: you can use `findElements` which returns a list of matching elements and get the second one

Comment: For example, there are 5 x's in total, the first one is disabled hence when I use the above code I displayed the option is "Disabled", how do I move to the next x instead of moving on to something else?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the locator below is unique on the page.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[original-title='Delete resolved']")).click();
```